# ReadXml в DataSet меняет столбцы местами

Tags: c#

Немного разобравшись пронял что проблема не в DataGridView

Из MS SQL я получаю такую таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С Помощью FOR XML RAW в запросе преобразую ее в:

```
<row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Кассир." UserName="Радыгина Айгуль Ирековна" _x0032_019-01-20="1" _x0032_019-01-21="1" Итого="2" />
<row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Кассир." UserName="Стрельникова Марина Андреевна" _x0032_019-01-22="1" _x0032_019-01-23="1" Итого="2" />
<row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Повар" UserName="Евстафьев Владимир Андреевич" _x0032_019-01-20="1" Итого="1" />
<row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Повар" UserName="Федоров Вадим Юрьевич" _x0032_019-01-21="1" _x0032_019-01-22="1" _x0032_019-01-23="1" Итого="3" />
```

Далее получаю это все с помощью

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(data, Connection);
XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader);
string reply = ds.GetXml();
```

в reply и передаю это string **reply**  уже клиенту

```
byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
handler.Send(msg);
```

И в нем уже столбцы не в правильном порядке:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Кассир." UserName="Радыгина Айгуль Ирековна" Итого="2" _x0032_019-01-20="1" _x0032_019-01-21="1">
    <row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Кассир." UserName="Стрельникова Марина Андреевна" _x0032_019-01-22="1" Итого="1" />
    <row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Повар" UserName="Евстафьев Владимир Андреевич" Итого="1" _x0032_019-01-20="1" />
    <row ConceptionName="021101С, Уфа, Окей, ул. Маршала Жукова, 37" mainRoleCode="Повар" UserName="Федоров Вадим Юрьевич" _x0032_019-01-22="1" Итого="2" _x0032_019-01-21="1" />
  </row>
</NewDataSet>
```

И вот как это исправить прошу помощи

Comment: 1. Согласно спецификации xml, порядок _атрибутов_ не определен. То есть они могут располагаться в любом порядке. Соответственно, xml-парсер при разборе может расположить их так, как ему удобно. Поэтому нельзя закладываться на порядок атрибутов.

Comment: 2. Имена колонок в гриде не совпадают с именами атрибутов. Вы их просто переименовываете (колонки при этом создаются автоматически) или вы делаете маппинг (колонки созданы вручную)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  колонки создаются автоматически, переименовываю  первые 3 колонки `dataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Торговая точка";`

Comment: Попробуйте отдельно передать схему данных (`GetXmlSchema`) или встроить схему в данные (`WriteXml` в режиме `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`)

Comment: @PavelMayorov а могли бы пример дать как это применить в моем случае

Comment: @Max не мог бы - я никогда не работал с DataSet